# What is the name of this chart?

Tags: charts, treemap

Is there a specific name for this kind of charts ? What JavaScript Charting Library has it ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look up **treemaps** / **treemapping**. This is how [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping) describes them:

> *"In information visualization and computing, treemapping is a method for displaying hierarchical data by using nested rectangles. […]*
>
> *Treemaps display hierarchical (tree-structured) data as a set of
>   nested rectangles. Each branch of the tree is given a rectangle, which
>   is then tiled with smaller rectangles representing sub-branches. A
>   leaf node's rectangle has an area proportional to a specified
>   dimension of the data."*

One notable tool which utilizes this technique is [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/). Their website also refers to this kind of visualization as a treemap.

Given this term, you should be able to easily find a JavaScript library that can produce them by simply performing [a web search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=treemaps+in+javascript). (I cannot recommend any of the following, since I haven't used them, but the linked Google search finds jsTreemap, Plotly.js, Google Charts, and a few others, on the very first result page.)

If you're curious about the algorithm(s) behind these diagrams, these papers might be of interest:

- [Brian Johnson, Ben Shneiderman (1991): *Treemaps: a space-filling approach to the visualization of hierarchical information structures*.](http://drum.lib.umd.edu/bitstream/handle/1903/370/CS-TR-2657.pdf;sequence=2)
- [Mark Bruls, Kees Huizing, Jarke van Wijk (1999): *Squarified Treemaps.*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.36.6685)

Answer (score 4):

It's called a [treemap](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/treemap/), and [ZingChart](https://www.zingchart.com/gallery/#Treemap) is a JavaScript charting library that has it. It's a useful way to chart hierarchical data. It also allows for user interaction since the user can further drilldown into the treemap. Check out the below demo.

```js
var myConfig = {
    "graphset":[
        {
            "type":"treemap",
            "plotarea":{
                "margin":"0 0 30 0"
            },
            "tooltip":{
                
            },
            "options":{
                
            },
            "series":[
                {
                    "text":"North America",
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "text":"United States",
                            "children":[
                                {
                                    "text":"Texas",
                                    "value":21
                                },
                                {
                                    "text":"California",
                                    "value":53
                                },
                                {
                                    "text":"Ohio",
                                    "value":12
                                },
                                {
                                    "text":"New York",
                                    "value":46
                                },
                                {
                                    "text":"Michigan",
                                    "value":39
                                },
                                {
                                    "text":"Alabama",
                                    "value":25
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "text":"Canada",
                            "value":113
                        },
                        {
                            "text":"Mexico",
                            "value":78
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "text":"Europe",
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "text":"France",
                            "value":42
                        },
                        {
                            "text":"Spain",
                            "value":28
                        },
                        {
                            "text":"Switzerland",
                            "value":13
                        },
                        {
                            "text":"Germany",
                            "value":56
                        },
                        {
                            "text":"Cyprus",
                            "value":7
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "text":"Africa",
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "text":"Egypt",
                            "value":22
                        },
                        {
                            "text":"Congo",
                            "value":38
                        },
                        {
                            "text":"Lesotho",
                            "value":9
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "text":"Asia",
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "text":"India",
                            "value":92
                        },
                        {
                            "text":"China",
                            "value":68
                        },
                        {
                            "text":"Mongolia",
                            "value":25
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "text":"South America",
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "text":"Brazil",
                            "value":42
                        },
                        {
                            "text":"Argentina",
                            "value":28
                        },
                        {
                            "text":"Peru",
                            "value":15
                        },
                        {
                            "text":"Uruguay",
                            "value":33
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "text":"Australia (continent)",
                    "children":[
                        {
                            "text":"Australia (country)",
                            "value":121
                        },
                        {
                            "text":"New Zealand",
                            "value":24
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 400, 
 width: 600 
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  <script>zingchart.MODULESDIR = "https://cdn.zingchart.com/modules/";
  ZC.LICENSE = ["569d52cefae586f634c54f86dc99e6a9","ee6b7db5b51705a13dc2339db3edaf6d"];</script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
 </body>
```

For more information on treemaps, read this blog post: https://blog.zingchart.com/2015/03/10/treemaps-charting/

Disclaimer: I'm on the ZingChart team. Let me know if you have more questions. Thanks!